# Python doesn't see packages with Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook

I use Jupyter Notebook with a virtual environment.
I have a dependency installed, but can't import it:

cell 1:
`!pip3 install sent2vec`

```
Requirement already satisfied: sent2vec in 
venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.0)
```

cell 2:
`import sent2vec`

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-06231d291a17> in <module>
----> 1 import sent2vec

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sent2vec'
```

How this can happen? How to fix this?

```
> pip3 list
Package      Version  
------------ ---------
certifi      2019.9.11
chardet      3.0.4    
Cython       0.29.14  
idna         2.8      
joblib       0.14.0   
langdetect   1.0.7    
nltk         3.4.4    
numpy        1.17.1   
pip          19.3.1   
requests     2.22.0   
scikit-learn 0.21.3   
scipy        1.3.2    
sent2vec     0.0.0    
setuptools   41.6.0   
six          1.13.0   
urllib3      1.25.7   
wheel        0.33.6
```

Comment: What happens when you run `which jupyter` from your terminal (assuming you're on a UNIX-based system)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll note that `jupyter` is not listed in your installed packages. That means you're running it from a different virtual environment. As I mentioned in the comment responding to your question, you can run `which jupyter` to find out where your Jupyter Notebook application is being run from (assuming you're on a *NIX system); in this case, it **won't be** from the `python3.7` virtual environment that shows up in your first code block.

To resolve the issue, you simply need to run `pip3 install jupyter`, then retry running `jupyter notebook`.

Alternatively, you can add your virtual environment as a kernel so that it can be selected when you're running Jupyter from your original environment. To do this, you would run (assuming `pip` is connected to your original environment):

```sh
pip install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user --name=<insert name of your venv>
```

You should then be able to select that venv as a kernel on new notebooks. ([Source](https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/) for info on venv activation in Jupyter).

Comment: The kernel install did it for me. In an activated environment with jupyter installed it should have automatically picked the correct kernel.

Answer (score 8):

Try by installing directly within Jupyter using the following command:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install your_package_name
```

Comment: After spending 1 whole day in investing the issue and finally your 1 line of code saves my day.. Thanks so much.. <3

Comment: how did you find this solution! why does it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Run this (with `envname` your enviroment name):

`jupyter kernelspec uninstall envname`

`ipython kernel install --user --name=envname`

Sometimes Jupyter doesnt update properly the kernels associated with enviroments.
So the solution is to uninstall it and install it again.

I had the same problem and this fixed it

Answer (score -1):

It apears that you need Numpy **1.17.1**(you have Numpy **1.16.0**) to use sent2vec

*requirements*  https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec/blob/master/requirements.txt

Comment: This didn't help.

Comment: hmm,it seems strange to me that version of package is 0.0.0  Try reinstaling or installing with setup.py from https://github.com/epfml/sent2vec